# Elastic Search cluster setup giving inconsistent search results while using pagination

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I've an Elastic Search(`version 6.8.23`) cluster of 2 nodes, 1 primary shard & 1 replica shard. Initially loaded with a few, around 1500, records into it.

Some details about the cluster are below:

Health Status: **Green**

Output of POST `/_cat/shards/<index-name>?v`

```
index    shard prirep state   docs store ip           node
index-6  0     p      STARTED 1546 6.5mb ***.***.**.1 node-1
index-6  0     r      STARTED 1546 6.5mb ***.***.**.2 node-2
```

Output of POST `/_cat/segments/<index-name>?v`

```
index    shard prirep ip           segment generation docs.count docs.deleted    size size.memory committed searchable version compound
index-6  0     p      ***.***.**.1 _4               4        154            4   1.9mb        8372 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     p      ***.***.**.1 _b              11       1303           78   3.5mb       38020 true      true       7.7.3   false
index-6  0     p      ***.***.**.1 _c              12         82            0 661.7kb       10525 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     p      ***.***.**.1 _d              13          6            0 367.4kb        4359 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     p      ***.***.**.1 _e              14          1            0   4.3kb        1635 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     r      ***.***.**.2 _6               6        173            7     2mb        8357 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     r      ***.***.**.2 _b              11         26            1  48.1kb        7229 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     r      ***.***.**.2 _c              12        994           67   2.8mb       30852 true      true       7.7.3   false
index-6  0     r      ***.***.**.2 _d              13        264            7 565.7kb        7866 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     r      ***.***.**.2 _e              14         82            0 661.7kb       10525 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     r      ***.***.**.2 _f              15          6            0 367.4kb        4359 true      true       7.7.3   true
index-6  0     r      ***.***.**.2 _g              16          1            0   4.3kb        1635 true      true       7.7.3   true
```

> Note: **compound** field false for couple of segments.

In this setup, if we hit the following search request multiple times, it give 2 different result sets(seems like different for each node/shard).

```
POST /index-6/_search?from=0&size=10
```

The results are not consistent every time.

Few questions:

1. Why it is giving inconsistent results?
2. Why the **compound** value is false for some segments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to paginate over your index, you also need to specify a sort value to make sure the pagination order is deterministic.

```
POST /index-6/_search?from=0&size=10&sort=id:asc
                                        ^
                                        |
                                   add sorting
```

Note that if your index is actively being written to, the order might change. If this is the case, in 6.8 you might want to resort to using the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-scroll.html) in order to freeze the search context for the duration of the scroll and return consistent results.

Regarding your second question, the `compound` boolean simply means that Lucene merged all files from the segment into a single file to save file descriptors (if true).

Comment: It seems to work fine with sort.